# html form post method to php in head section

Tags: php, html, post

I am just experimenting with some databases for my webshop.
And right now I try to add products through an admin pages to my database.
I have this in :

```
<?php
function test(){the code}
?>
```

and in body I have a form with this:

```
<form action="test()" method="post">
</form>
```

Is this possible to do with xHTML or not?
If not what would be the best way?

Comment: Action attribute cant be used for triggering a php function, it is done server-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use PHP and a form to submit data just use this example:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$myvar = $_POST['myvar'];
echo $myvar;
}
?>
<form action='' method='POST'>
<input type='text' name='myvar'>
<input type='submit' name='submit'>
</form>
```

Now if you want to use that data in a javascript function try.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myfunction(){
var MyData = document.getElementById('myvar').value;
}
</script>
<form action='' method='POST'>
    <input type='text' id='myvar'>
    <input type='submit' onClick='myfunction()' id='submit'>
    </form>
```

Comment: why is there no action in form?

Comment: @MustiHakan: Action specifies what link your page would redirect to when the form is submitted; by default if action='' then the page will redirect to itself.

Comment: thank you for answering so quickly :)
I can't even accept it as my answer yet!

Comment: @MustiHakan: No problem I am glad to help, and that is interesting I did not know that StackOverflow had a time-limit before you could accept answers, please just accept it whenever the time-limit expires so other people know your question is answered. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

In the action property you must specify the php filename not a function, for example:
if you have :

```
<?php
function test(){the code}
?>
```

you've got to call the function :

```
<?php
    function test(){the code}
     test();
    ?>
```

let's suppose this code is in databaseOp.php, you must then set the action property accordingly in the html file:

```
<form action="databaseOp.php" method="post">
</form>
```

When you hit submit the databaseOp.php script will run and of course the test() function within it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add GET parameter to the action path in order to determine, which function must be executed.

```
<form action="process.php?function=test" method="post">
</form>
```

In process.php you may have something like that:

```
<?php

    switch(@$_GET["function"])
    {

        case "test":
        test();
        break;

        case "test2":
        test2();
        break;

    }

?>
```